# Is the use of 1/8 NPT ports on pitot/static instruments derived from an FAA standard?

Tags: faa-regulations, avionics, aircraft-certification, pitot-static

On almost every pitot-static instrument used in general aviation aircraft, a 1/8 female NPT port is provided to connect the instrument to the pitot-static system. I was told that is is a requirement from the FAA but I have been unable to find any such requirement listed in any [TSO document](https://drs.faa.gov/browse). Is this actually a design requirement or just a commonly-used standard?

[image]

Comment: There are at least several certified products on the market that do not use this port style, and I'm not aware of any requirement for what port style to use. I'd guess it may be simply commonly used based on the age of the design.

Comment: @selectstriker2, can you give me some examples of the certified products that you are referring to?

Comment: This is a good question. TSO C10c for altimeters, for example, does not specify the pitot/static port hardware.